# BIM Model clipping issues in Unity 2020

Tags: unity-game-engine, clipping, bim, unity3d-shaders

I have BIM model that I am using in 2018 version of Unity engine. When import the model into my project on 2019 OR 2020 version of the Unity engine, clippings on certain surfaces of the model occurs.

Has anyone encountered this issue with Unity 2020? Any solutions that can be suggested for me to try?

Examples attached.

Appreciate any help in advance...

[Unity 2018 Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8D9mV.png)

[Unity 2020 Version - same BIM but with Clipping Issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIIji.jpg)